# constexpr reference to avr port address

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, avr, constexpr

I am playing a bit with avr microcontrollers and C++14. While trying to implement a C++ wrapper for the io pins I stumbled upon an error.

The idea was, to let the wrapper take the `sfr`s as template argument to easy optimaizion for compiler (don't want an extra function there and using template arguments I can indicate to the compiler, that my arguments should always be compile-time evaluateable). I thought, that one can have `constexpr uint8_t& x = ...` variables referencing some compile-time known address. But the following does not work (the defines are taken from the avr includes):

```
#include <avr/io.h>

constexpr uint32_t addr[] = { _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB) };

constexpr uint32_t GetAddr()
{
    return addr[0];
}

constexpr decltype(auto) Get()
{
    _SFR_IO8(GetAddr());
}

int main() {
    auto addr = GetAddr();
    auto b = Get();

    _SFR_IO8(addr) &= ~(1 << 2);
    b |= (1 << 3);
}
```

It gives me `error: expression '*(volatile uint8_t*)(GetAddr() + 32u)' has side-effects` in the `Get()` function. Replacing `decltype(auto)` with `uint8_t&` (of course) did not help.

Why can't I obtain a `constexpr uint8_t` reference pointing to the memory location at `_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB) = (volatile uint8_t*)(_SFR_IO8(5u) - 32u) = (volatile uint8_t*)(5u + 32u - 32u)`?

Comment: `constexpr` must be a constant expression, at compile time

Comment: Why do you want `Get()` to be `constexpr`? It returns a reference to some volatile IO memory. The value at that memory location is not constant by definition. I guess that you get the shortest possible assembly when you define the function as `static`, but not `constexpr`.

Comment: "*Replacing `decltype(auto)` with `uint8_t&` (of course) did not help.*" Well, `GetAddr` returns an rvalue, so in turn trying to return an lvalue reference to that rvalue _should_ fail. I've no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish...

Comment: I want to tell the compiler, that whatever the reference points to, [is an object with static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Reference_constant_expression). Though after thinking about it, I don't know, if this will actually buy me something.

Comment: But why do you want `GetAddr` to return a value and `Get` to return a reference? Pick one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a constexpr pointer to a register on embedded system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037386/how-to-create-a-constexpr-pointer-to-a-register-on-embedded-system)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a similar templated compile time reducible to a single instruction. I had to use some template metaprogramming to make this work.

A stripped down example:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

struct A {
  constexpr static volatile uint8_t *const PORT() { return &PORTA; }
  constexpr static volatile uint8_t *const DDR() { return &DDRA; }
};

template <class port, u1 pin> class IOpin {
  constexpr static volatile uint8_t  *DDR = port::DDR();
  constexpr static volatile uint8_t *PORT = port::PORT();
  constexpr static uint8_t mask = 1 << pin;

public:
  inline IOpin() {}

  inline static void output() { *DDR |= mask; }
  inline static void input() { *DDR &= ~mask; }
  inline static void set() { *PORT |= mask; }
}

// Use as type or instance
using myPinType = IOpin<A, 1>;
IOpin<A, 1> myPinInstance;

// Use myPin
myPinType::set(true);
myPinInstance.output();
```

*Full implementation: https://github.com/cinderblock/AVR/blob/master/AVR%2B%2B/IOpin.hpp*

Answer (score 0):

I was working with something like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

constexpr uint8_t INPUT        =0;
constexpr uint8_t OUTPUT       =1; // output + set pin LOW
constexpr uint8_t OUTPUT_LOW   =1; // output + set pin LOW
constexpr uint8_t INPUT_PULLUP =2;
constexpr uint8_t OUTPUT_HIGH  =3; // output + set pin HIGH

struct pin_setting {
    uint8_t p;        // PORTx is enough, because DDRx is allway -1, PINX -2
  uint8_t bit_mask;
}; 

//#define MEM8_OFFSET 0x100 // for megaxxx0
constexpr pin_setting pins[] {
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD0)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD1)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD2)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD3)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD4)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD5)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD6)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTD, _BV(PD7)},

  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB0)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB1)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB2)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB3)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB4)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTB, _BV(PB5)},

  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC0)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC1)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC2)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC3)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC4)},
  {(uint16_t)&PORTC, _BV(PC5)}
};

inline void mDigitalSet(uint8_t pin) {
  _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p) |= pins[pin].bit_mask;
}

inline void mDigitalClr(uint8_t pin) {
  _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p) &= ~pins[pin].bit_mask;
}

inline void mDigitalToggle(uint8_t pin) {
  _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p-2) = pins[pin].bit_mask;
}

inline void mDigitalWrite(uint8_t pin, bool level=true) {
  level ? mDigitalSet(pin) : mDigitalClr(pin);
}

inline bool mDigitalRead(uint8_t pin) {
  return _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p-2) & pins[pin].bit_mask;
}

inline void mPinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t dir) {
  if (dir & 1) {
    _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p-1) |= pins[pin].bit_mask;
  } else {
    _SFR_IO8(pins[pin].p-1) &= ~pins[pin].bit_mask;
    }
  mDigitalWrite(pin, dir&2);
}
```

It's not perfect and it can be done better. (It was just proof of concept, it was never used)

The Arduino stores `SFR` pointers into the `PROGMEM` in the same way - as `uint16_t`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is outside the C++ standard. The expression `(uint16_t)&PORTD` hides a `reinterpret_cast`, and such expressions are not compile time constant. GCC happens to accept them, but they may change their mind in future versions and reject it to be conformant with the Standard.