# cast pointer to unsigned int in a switch case in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have a `C` header file that has a list of definitions like below

```
#define TAG_A   ((A*)0x123456)
#define TAG_B   ((B*)0x456789)
```

I include that file in a `cpp` file.
I want to cast those definition in a `switch` `case` like below

```
unsigned int get_tag_address(unsigned int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(TAG_A):
        return 1;
        case reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(TAG_B):
        return 2;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

I still get compiler error that I can't cast a pointer to an unsigned intigeter.

What do I do wrong?

The definitions look at hardware addresses of an embedded system. I want to return an unsigned integer based on what hardware component is used (i.e. passed into the function argument).
This is how I ended up in that situation.

PS: The header file containing the defitions **must not change**.

Comment: the compiler error is rather clear. You cannot cast a pointer to an unsigned integer. Why do you want that?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to get only the address and keep it in a variable.

Comment: what is `i` ? Is there a common base class of `A` and `B` ?

Comment: You want to keep it in a variable or you want to use it as a switch case value?

Comment: @MrBit If you want the address, then store that address in the type that was designed to hold that type of information, namely a pointer type.

Comment: Assuming that you need to use the value in a switch case by any means necessary, and *casting* is an X-Y problem, you might try a combination of (a) token-stringizing preprocessor operator, (b) raw string literals, and (c) a `constexpr` or `consteval` parsing function to which you pass the raw string literal.  `reinterpret_cast` will not be a part of any viable solution, because `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used inside constant expression evaluation.

Comment: how did you get into the situation that `i`  holds the adress of either an `A` or a `B` in the first place?

Comment: If this is that preprocessor symbol, a C-style cast of `(unsigned int)` is what's needed.

Comment: `case` values must be constant expressions, and `reinterpret_cast` is not considered a constant expression.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type

Comment: @NathanOliver the header file containing the addresses isn't mine and it must not change.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67038297/3840170

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use `TAG_A` and `TAG_B` in a `case` of a `switch`, except by using preprocessor tricks like stringifying the macro replacement itself in a macro and then parsing the value form the resulting string, which will however make the construct dependent on the exact form of the `TAG_X` macros and I feel is not really worth it when you don't have a strict requirement to obtain compile-time constant values representing the pointers.

The results of the expressions produced by the `TAG_A` and `TAG_B` replacement can not be used in a `case` operand because the operand must be a constant expression, but casting an integer to a pointer as done with `(A*)` and `(B*)` disqualifies an expression from being a constant expression.

So, you will need to use `if`/`else if` instead:

```
unsigned int get_tag_address(unsigned int i)
{
    if(i == reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(TAG_A)) {
        return 1;
    } else if(i == reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(TAG_B)) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Also, consider using `std::uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned int` for `i` and in the `reinterpret_cast`s, since it is not guaranteed that `unsigned int` is large enough to hold the pointer values. However, compilation of the `reinterpret_cast` should fail if `unsigned int` is in fact too small. (It is possible that `std::uintptr_t` in `<cstdint>` does not exist, in which case you are either using pre-C++11 or, if not that, it would be a hint that the architecture does not allow for representing pointers as integer values. It is not guaranteed that this is possible, but you would need to be working some pretty exotic architecture for it to not be possible.)

And if you can, simply pass, store and compare pointers (maybe as `void*`) instead of integer values representing the pointers. That is safer for multiple reasons and always guaranteed to work.

Comment: "It is fundamentally impossible to use TAG_A and TAG_B in a case of a switch" This is not quite true. Stringize it, extract the number, convert to integer. All is doable with the preprocessor and constexpr functions. You should know the format of the `#define` but this is not a show-stopper.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes true, I really meant the expression resulting from the `TAG_X` replacement. I doubt that the macro tricks are worth it here though. I modified the answer accordingly.